# How do I keep the elements inside the container filling the parent container as I scale

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I change the scale of the elements inside the scrollarea, how do the elements inside the scrollarea stay close to the top, bottom, left, and right sides of the parent container
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBZnC.gif)

```js
function changeScale (f) {
    let cc = document.getElementById("cc")
    let n = cc.style.transform.length > 0 ? Number(cc.style.transform.substring(6,cc.style.transform.length-1)) : 1
    if (f === 'zoomIn') {
        n += 0.05
    } else if (f === 'zoomOut') {
        n -= 0.05
    } else if (f === 'restore') {
        n = 1
    } else {
        n = f
    }
    cc.style.transform = "scale(" + n + ")"
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute;left: 50px;top: 50px;">
    <button onclick="changeScale('zoomIn')" style="float:left;">zoomIn</button>
    <button onclick="changeScale('zoomOut')" style="float:left;">zoomOut</button>
    <button onclick="changeScale('restore')" style="float:left;">restore</button>
</div>
<div id=app>
    <div id="el" style="width: 400px;height:400px;margin: 200px auto;border:1px solid blue;overflow:auto;">
        <div id="cc" style="width:800px;height:800px;border:2px solid red;z-index:10">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/hello_wzq/rbga3nzs/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `transform-origin` value to: `top left`. Here is a working example:

```js
function changeScale (f) {
    let cc = document.getElementById("cc")
    let n = cc.style.transform.length > 0 ? Number(cc.style.transform.substring(6,cc.style.transform.length-1)) : 1
    if (f === 'zoomIn') {
        n += 0.05
    } else if (f === 'zoomOut') {
        n -= 0.05
    } else if (f === 'restore') {
        n = 1
    } else {
        n = f
    }
    cc.style.transform = "scale(" + n + ")"
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute;left: 50px;top: 50px;">
    <button onclick="changeScale('zoomIn')" style="float:left;">zoomIn</button>
    <button onclick="changeScale('zoomOut')" style="float:left;">zoomOut</button>
    <button onclick="changeScale('restore')" style="float:left;">restore</button>
</div>
<div id=app>
    <div id="el" style="width: 400px;height:400px;margin: 200px auto;border:1px solid blue;overflow:auto;">
        <div id="cc" style="width:800px;height:800px;border:2px solid red;z-index:10;transform-origin: left top;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you.no problem zooming in, but I still had the same problem zooming out